# A way to solve matrices within equation

Tags: linear-algebra

Solve for X
$$2X+X^t=B$$
Where $X,B, $are matrices, and $ X^t$ stands for transpose.
I was trying to work with indices but it doesn't seems to work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note taking the transpose of the equation $2X+ X^T = B$, we get that
$$2X^T + X = B^T$$
Solving which gives us
$$2(B-2X) + X = B^T \implies X = \dfrac{2B-B^T}3 \text{ and } X^T = \dfrac{2B^T-B}3$$

Answer (score 3):

Apply transposition to your equation. Then you get two linear equations with unknowns $X$ and $X^t$. Solve this system.

Answer (score 2):

$$(2X+X^t)^t=B^t\implies 2X^t+X=B^t\implies X^t=(B^t-X)/2\implies$$

$$\implies2X+(B^t-X)/2=B\implies 2X-X/2=B-B^t/2\implies$$
$$\implies 3X/2= B-B^t/2\implies X=(2/3)B -(1/3)B^t$$